# How to transmit data from an interrupt handler to an user application?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, driver, interrupt

A device that produces an interrupt is managed by a handler in the kernel. I need to send a message with a flag, so that the user application receives the notification of an interruption has occurred, and thus can perform a procedure. For example, wake up a process.
How do I do this?

Comment: do you have a specific device in mind?

Comment: I have a linux device driver for an IPCore processor, that interrupt with 5 lines of IRQ

Comment: what physical device is connected to one or more of the 5 lines?

Comment: just 5 lines, IRQ: 91, 90, 89, 88, 87. The device is the IPCore (is in the FPGA, of the development hardware ZedBoard)

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the POSIX style solution would be to write a device driver that receives the interrupts in the kernel. The user space program would open a device file and icoctl() or read() from it, blocking until at least one event had arrived. I suggest, that the user space program should actually read a bit more:

- How many events have arrived so far?)
- Has the call blocked (e.g. there were no events queued when reading from the device)

This would help you, to see when your program is misisng events (e.g. because it has ben deleayed in the previous cycle).

Comment: In what way would awaken the process to do the reading? With a semaphore?
That is, a reading process, and falls asleep in the device_read code. Then the interrupt handler would awaken him. It's that what you tell me?

If the user process runs normally, my desire is that since the kernel will send a signal to the application.
If readings are taken from the user application, which I have in mind is that the interrupt handler changes the value of a variable in the driver gobal, and read the value in reading. But this solution does not seem very good.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use Netlink as an IPC between kernel and user-space. Just make sure to allocate the message using GFP_ATOMIC (in netlink_broadcast) to make sure you don't sleep in the irq. Have a look [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7356) for an Netlink tutorial.

Comment: I've also thought in IPC as an alternative, thank you, I'll read that now.

Comment: I found it a bit tricky. Something easier to implement can be an IPC mechanism such as semaphores. Can be achieved communication between the kernel and the user process like this? Or this IPC communication is only for user-level processes?????

Comment: Semaphores can be used as an IPC between user-space processes or as a synchronization primitive (user-space or kernel). You cannot use semaphores alone to pass messages between user-space and kernel domain.